# What is sampling bias?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

From the definitions I've read online they all go something like this...

> Sampling bias occurs when some members of a population are systematically more likely to be selected in a sample than others.

I'm going through a biometrics course at my university and while looking at the answer keys to previous exams, there are questions about hypothetical studies with regards to identifying bad sampling that have "bias" as an answer and don't seem to meet the definition in the course or else where.

For academic integrity reasons I won't post the exact questions, but I suppose an example of such would be...

> A large portion of fish were able to escape from your fishing net because there was a small hole on the side of it. What is the obvious issue with this sampling?

How exactly would this be a "biased" sample if it isn't systemic?

Comment: Obviously, small fish are more likely to escape from a small hole than large fish are.

Comment: @lulu That makes sense. So if any portion of the sample has an advantage in some way like in the example, it's considered sampling bias?

Comment: "academic integrity" is perhaps better met with being honest with your exact sources, and not hiding in anonymity.

Comment: Well, yes.  One could  argue that one only really cares if the bias is correlated to the thing you are studying.  If I want to assess the percentage of extremely introverted individuals, I should not call for volunteers to step to the front of the room.  But as a practical matter it can be very hard to decide if a bias is correlated to your test or not.

Comment: If you want a random sample of _families_ in a school district, you'd get a biased sample by sampling _children_ at random from district schools. Families with more children in school are more likely to be chosen